# Children loop html append into parent loop inserted div by javascript

Tags: javascript

The loop working but don't getting class as a selector from parent loop generated div...

```
var parentdiv = $(".pDiv");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $(parentdiv).append("<label class="
        addLabel ">" + i + "</label>"); // parent loop add
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        $(".addLabel").append("<label class="
            addLabel2 ">" + j + "</label>"); //children loop in parent class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your text has too many mistakes and it's hard to understand what exactly is the problem. 
Secondly - your string in `append()` function **is not concatenated properly** as `addLabel` doesn't seem to be a variable. Try this: 
 
`$(parentdiv).append("<label class='addLabel"+ i +"'></label>")` and 
`$(".addLabel").append("<label class='addLabel"+ j +"'></label>");`

Comment: Sorry! This is not my code. This is only an example you are right about append string.But that's not my question, My question is: How to get "addLabel" as a selector to append an another loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved the children loop :

```
//children loop start
for (var c = 0; c < checkBoxs.length; c++) {
    // Things[i]                
    console.log(c);
    var multiInputs = $("#myframe1").contents().find(".div2");  // iframe parent div
    var putIntoParent = $(multiInputs).children(); // selector as parent children
    var getMultiInput = multiInputs.selector;
    //$(multiInputs).append('<lable><input type="checkbox"/>'+ checkBoxs[c].label +' </label>');
    var node = document.createElement('span');
    //var inputPlace = document.querySelector('.inputField_add');
    console.log(multiInputs)
    // $(multiInputs).on("load", function() {
    $(putIntoParent).append('<lable><input type="checkbox"/>'+ checkBoxs[c].label +' </label>');
    // });                  
}
```